# I am trying to setup React storybook with an ejected version of create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am trying to setup React storybook with an ejected version of create-react-app.

```
// config.js
import { configure } from '@storybook/react';
import i18n from 'i18n';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';

const Root = story => (
  <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
    <App {...rest} />
  </I18nextProvider>
);

function loadStories() {
  require('../src/components/Home/Slip/Slip.story.js');
  // You can require as many stories as you need.
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

Following is the story :

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React from 'react';
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';

import Slip from './Slip.component';

const data = {...}

storiesOf('Footer', module).add('with text', () => (
  <Slip data={data} />
));
```

I am getting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWmEI.png)

Can someone help me out here ?

Comment: Could you convert your screenshot of the error to text? We can answer better that way.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain "type error : Cannot read property "wait" of null